# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el check-box quede abajo del formulario? wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Buen día a todos.
Estoy intentando poner este formulario para que los clientes queden subscritos al newsletter por medio del plugin MC4WP pero todo lo que agrego me queda en la misma fila.
Intenté usar la etiqueta `<br>` pero no funcionó.

Estas son las etiquetas usadas:

```
  <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required />
  
  <input type="submit" value="Suscribirse" /> 

<label>
    <input name="AGREE_TO_TERMS" type="checkbox" value="1" required="">He leído y acepto los términos y condiciones
</label>
```

Su apariencia en el editor se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el web-site se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Como no se que propiedades css les estas agregando, prueba con esto:

```
<label style="display: block;width: 100%;float: none;clear: both;">
    <input name="AGREE_TO_TERMS" type="checkbox" value="1" required="">He leído y acepto los términos y condiciones
</label>
```

Esto lo agrega en bloque, le da un tamaño del 100% del espacio y elimina la propiedad de flotar en caso de que la tenga.

También podrías agruparlo en divs y dar tus estilos css según sea necesario.